# Generating data frames, but only getting 1 row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, faker

I wish to create a dataframe using faker library in Python, but I am able to get only a single row, dont understand whats the issue in the code. here's the same:

```
import pandas as pd

for dat in range(int(input())):
    dat = [[fake.email(),fake.phone_number(),fake.address(),fake.name(),fake.date(),fake.pyint(0,3)]]

v = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=['Email','PhNo','Address','Name','Date','Children'])
```

If I see columns in `v` by printing or head function, i can see only 1 row.
I wish to see the entire no of rows based on the user input, say if its 3, then 3 rows should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just updating the 'dat' value in every iteration. First create a list and then add data.

```
import pandas as pd
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
dat = []
for i in range(int(input())):
dat.append([fake.email(),fake.phone_number(),fake.address(),fake.name(),fake.date(),fake.pyint(0,3)])

v= pd.DataFrame(dat, columns =['Email','PhNo','Address','Name','Date','Children'])
print(v)
```

Comment: If i want to generate a fake text whose characters is in between a-c, what should be done?

Comment: import random
def atoc():
  res = ''
  for i in range(0,10):
    res=res+random.choice('abc')
  return res
print(atoc())

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite `dat` in each loop. You need to append the new data to the existing:

```
dat = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
   dat.append([fake.email(), fake.phone_number(), fake.address(), fake.name(), fake.date(), fake.pyint(0,3)])
```

Comment: If i want to generate a fake text whose characters is in between a-c, what should be done?